# Time complexity of search algorithms?

Tags: complexity-theory, search-algorithms, lower-bounds

Can we prove that classical search algorithms cannot do better than a binary search algorithm with complexity $O(log(n))$ ?
If so, how do we prove it?

Comment: I'm assuming you are considering sorted collections of elements (otherwise you can't even do better than $\Omega(n)$).

Comment: (@Steven `considering [ordered] collections of elements` make that *preprocessed* - think hash-table.)

Comment: @greybeard, that's why my answer tanks about comparison-based algorithms ;)

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be a comparison-based search algorithm that takes a collection $C$ of $n$ elements and an element $x$ as input and outputs the position of $x$ in $C$, or reports that $x \not\in C$.

Let $c(n)$ be the maximum number of comparisons performed by $A$ over all possible inputs where $C$ has $n$ elements.
Since $A$ needs to be able to return $1+n$ different outputs, and each comparison can only return two different outcomes, we need to have $2^{c(n)} \ge n+1$, hence $c(n) \ge \lceil \log(n+1)\rceil = \Omega(\log n)$. The number of comparisons is also a lower bound to the running time of $A$.